# How to get the current language environment (SET COUNTRY)?

Tags: abap

I have a bug where a `WRITE ... TO` statement with a date as its source behaves differently between the first and subsequent calls of the program. The first time the date is written in `dd.mm.yyyy` format, then in all subsequent calls until I exit the parent transaction, it is written in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. There is no `SET COUNTRY` statement nearby. I would like to see what is the current language environment and set watchpoint on it if possible.

Comment: You question is unclear. If your question is about how to stop at each statement `SET COUNTRY` then your title is misleading because you ask how to get the current language environment. You also assume that the statement `WRITE ... TO` is buggy, why? (I'm pretty sure it's not bugged, but you may check SAP notes) Could you clarify please?

Comment: if WRITE format changes, then some program or statement in the call stack changes locale implicitly, you should find out which one. I believe you cannot set watchpoint on this change

Comment: consider also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409635/determining-the-active-formatting-settings-in-abap, it is somehow related to yours

Comment: @SandraRossi the `WRITE ... TO` statement is not buggy, but the fact that it is executed in a changing context is causing a bug. I need to confirm that the language environment is changing between program calls (hence my question), then investigate the reason for the changing language environment. It is most likely caused by a `SET COUNTRY` statement but that's only a hypothesis.

Comment: With the debugger, it's easy to stop each time `SET COUNTRY` is executed (menu "breakpoint at statement"). You may also do a SQL trace on **buffered** tables, you will find an access to the table `T005X` each time `SET COUNTRY` is used.